# Dynamo DB for .net: Try catch block

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created .net based web api that connects to dynamo db and returns data. What I want to know is how can we wrap this in a try catch block so that it catches and throws appropriate exception as well as some status code since its an api. Below is the code that I use. I am not sure what exception to raise against dynamo db.

```
   [HttpGet("api/data")]
    public Task<List<UserData>> GetData()
    {
        var creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsId, awsPassword);
        var dynamoClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds, awsDynamoDbRegion);
        var context = new DynamoDBContext(dynamoClient);
        List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        var response = context.ScanAsync<UserData>(conditions);
        return response.GetNextSetAsync();            
    }
```

Also wanted to know if I need to make any code changes above to follow best practices in terms of structuring my code. So I have the lines of declaring the context and connecting to dynamo db in every api call. Is this the correct way to go.?

Comment: This is an obscure question. Please give us all the details required to be able to run your code and see how it works.

Comment: The code already works fine. I wanted to know how can I catch any amazon or dynamo db exception above.

Comment: That's awesome. Please give us all the details required to be able to run your code and see how it works.